# What is single word for a Strategic action

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word to describe "strategic actions".  These actions would be performed multiple times a week at a minimum, at best multiple times a day.

I'm not a big fan of the word "Lead" but others have used this term, for example: "Have you completed your leads this week".

I would like to use the word "Dailies".  For example: "Have you completed your dailies this week".  Unfortunately dailies are a little to strict since not all strategic actions are required daily.  Also daily loses some meaning, as these are strategic actions taken towards a goal.

Example Dailies/Leads

- Learn and use a customers name 5 times daily.
- Develop a call plan prior to making a customer call twice daily
- Eat an apple before dinner and lunch 10 times weekly
- Complete 4 micro-walks (250 steps) during work hours daily

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you give an example of what some of these 'strategic actions', 'leads' or 'dailies' are? What kinds of actions are included among them?

Comment: 'Task'? Definitely not 'dailies'...

Comment: Why not just use *strategics* or coin a new abbreviation such as *strats* or *stratties*, please?

Personally, I wonder both why you'd want a single word for *strategic actions* and how anything which basically belongs to the broad sweep of policy could be performed weekly, let alone several times daily.

Comment: Imagine a team trying to create a new habit among all its members for the purpose of creating a new habit that supports achievement of a goal which seems otherwise non-influenceable.  For example, lets say a hotel is trying to improve customer satisfaction (something they feel they can't influence), but if they do their "dailies" using a customers name 10 times a day ... and the entire team does that ... they start to notice feedback improve.  Its a tactic / behavior / habit-to-be / experiment thing that shouldn't be boring (like a task).  Word should be fun & reinforce frequency and purpose.

Comment: Example "Dailies" 1) Learn and use a customers name 5 times daily.  2) Develop a call plan prior to making customers call twice daily 3) Eat an apple before dinner and lunch 10 times weekly

Comment: "ploy" comes close but has a distinctly negative connotation akin to trickery

Comment: How about **rituals**?

Comment: Closely connected with _strategic_ is **strategem**, which in my head is pronounced in a French accent due to its use in the wonderful film _Amelie_.

Comment: *goals* or *tasks*?

Comment: *missions* or *objectives*?  Although there is no travelling abroad in the situations you have given as examples, I often hear people say "My **mission** for today is to accomplish [something] or "my **objectives** today are to complete [these things].

Answer (score 2):

Having thought on this during my commute, I'm not convinced there is a good single-word answer which incorporates all the following:

- Regular / Daily / Routine
- Strategic / Important
- Fun

Depending on quite what the role of this word is to be, you might want to consider using an acronym. Here are three I came up with:

> **Star Jump**
>
> - Strategic
> - Task
> - At
> - Regular
> - Junctures
> - Undertaken to
> - Maximize
> - Performance

Usage: Have you done your star jumps today?

It's nice to include "star" here since it has obvious connotations of quality, both of the task and of the person performing it.

> **Adventure**
>
> - Awesome
> - Daily
> - Virtue
> - Ever
> - Necessary
> - To
> - Undertake,
> - Realising
> - Excellence

Usage: Have you completed/gone on your adventures?

> **Parrot**
>
> - Positively
> - Awesome
> - Routine
> - Ritual
> - Or
> - Task

Usage: Have you taken care of your parrots?

---

Posted as a separate answer since it takes a completely different approach  to my first one.

Comment: I added a third. It's addictive!

Comment: Similar to Parrot is **Hamster** which I've given a recursive acronym: Hamsters
Are
Meaningful
Strategic
Tasks
Enacted
Regularly.

Comment: These are some incredible thoughts!!! Wow!   I need to think about this :)

Comment: The better the answers the more I realize how much is missing from my question.  Consider these qualities: "Predictive" and "Influenceable".  For example, I may set a goal to make a sell but it's not influenceable I can't DIRECTLY force someone to buy.  I can, however, influence making a sales call .. and if I do it enough it "predicts" the sell.  A big quality of these daily goals is that I have 100% control over doing them.  I guess "task" implies influencable.

Comment: Understood ... that's one of the nice things about "habits" as mentioned in @MikeJRamsey56's answer.

Comment: **Hamster** could be reworked into: **H**abits **A**imed at **M**eaningful **S**trategic **T**argets **E**ncouraging **R**esults ... or something along those lines.

Comment: I've also been thinking of "Mini-Mission" or "Micro-Mission", which might work in it's own right or as part of an acronym.

Comment: Some extra fodder for your consideration: Covey breaks down measurements into "Lead Measurements" and "Lag Measurements".  Lag measurements take a while to come in, and Lead measurements are more real time.  A Lag measurement might be quarterly sales figures, a Lead Measurement might be client site visits.  Similarly a "Lead Behavior" is an influenceable and predictive behavior that we commit to experimenting with to see if it drives the lag.

Comment: Or perhaps reading more like English, **Hamster**s could be: **H**abits **A**nd **M**icro **S**trategies **T**o **E**ncourage **R**esults.

Comment: Another potentially useful word is **Nudge**, as in "Nudging things in the right direction". Haven't read it, but was thinking of [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nudge-Improving-Decisions-Health-Happiness/dp/0141040017/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1499325959&sr=8-1&keywords=nudge).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, given your description **strategics** seems a natural choice. Technically that doesn't seem to exist (yet) as a noun (although see this [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=strategic_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrategic_NOUN%3B%2Cc0)), but the meaning should be obvious. Assuming you've considered and rejected that ...

> **Routine** *noun*
>
> 1. a customary or regular course of procedure.
> 2. commonplace tasks, chores, or duties as must be done regularly or at specified intervals; typical or everyday activity:
>      the routine of an office.
>
> Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/routine?s=t)

Unfortunately, this doesn't convey the idea of importance that **strategic** does. Of course you could combine them into **strategic routines**, but that may be a bit long.

Another possibility similar to **strategics** would be **programmatics**, which again doesn't (yet) exist as a noun, but is pleasing in implying the item forms part of a wider plan, and so suggests both importance and occuring as part of a schedule.

> **Programmatic** *adjective*
>
> - of, having, advocating, resembling, or following a plan, policy, or program
>
> Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/programmatic)

In my earlier comments, I suggested **ritual** which might work if you can see past the religious connotations, and **stratagem**, which is unfortunately similar to **ploy** in suggesting trickery.

Comment: Having just re-read the comments on the OP, I see that  you wanted the word to be "fun". That might seem to probably ruleout "routines" and I dare say makes "programmatics" awkward too. However if you can get people to think of routines as choreographed dance routines, that might turn it around. For "programmatics" you could abbreviate to "progs" which then connects you to "prog" and ideas of "progressive" and potentially also to "prog rock" which may be bad or good depending on taste.

Answer (score 1):

Circuit or circuits would work in some cases:

Circuit: a regular tour around an assigned district or territory. MW

I completed my four micro-walk circuits today.

I completed my weekly sales circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **imperatives**.  See for example ["The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People" by Stephen R. Covey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_7_Habits_of_Highly_Effective_People). An imperative is something that you believe in so strongly (e.g. moral imperative) that it compels you to act.

Comment: imperative is too strong for this application.  I didn't mention it in the question but dailies/leads etc start out as guesses, and we "bet" that if we do them they will pay off.  If we are consistent with them (for a few months) and they don't create the result - then we actually stop them and try other guesses.

Comment: @jrhicks hypothetical imperatives. :-)